# can a SOAP endpoint and a REST endpoint have the same uri path?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, soap

I have a Spring Boot project that supports both SOAP and REST endpoints.  Now I have a business requirement that they need to be accessed on the same URI context:

SOAP endpoints: app-context/wsdl-location

REST endpoints: app-context/rest-uri

Everything I have tried so far has resulted in a "405 Method not allowed" error. Also, there is a desire to do this through annotations as much as possible.

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT 1:

Here is the SOAP config to generate the WSDL (URI is the SOAP URI where the wsdl is exposed):

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext context) {
  MessageDispatcherServlet messageDispatcherServlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
  messageDispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(context);
  messageDispatcherServlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
  return new ServletRegistrationBean(messageDispatcherServlet, URI + "/*");
```

}

```
@Bean
 public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema awadSchema) {
  DefaultWsdl11Definition definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
  definition.setPortTypeName();  //cannot state port type name
  definition.setTargetNamespace(); //cannot state namespace
  definition.setLocationUri(URI);
  definition.setSchema(awadSchema);
  return definition;
```

}

```
@Bean
public XsdSchema awadSchema() {
  return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("/WEB-INF/xsd-file-name"));
```

}

Business wants to keep the uri the same and have the REST endpoints append off of it:  URI/report/.....

I have tried :

1) making the soap uri the servlet context path in application.properties

2)explicitly giving the full uri  in the REST mapping

3) trying to @Order to make it evaluate the REST endpoint first

4) setting the order in web.xml

As long as they have the same context the application tries to send the REST request through the wsdl and I get a 405 error

Comment: Could you describe exactly what you have tried so far?